# Bootstrap panel: collapsed on mobile but expanded on desktop, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I as simply as possible remove the class "in" from the div with id "panel-login" if the screen are smaller than 1199px (Bootstrap's xs, sm and md modes). I guess some kind of JS or JQuery could solve it but I'm not very good at either.

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Login</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel-login"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="panel-login" class="panel-collapse collapse in">

        <div class="panel-body">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?=$php_self?>?page=login&view=signup">Create account</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?=$php_self?>?page=login&view=reset_password">Reset password</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?=$php_self?>?page=login&view=reactivate_account">Reactivate account</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!-- end panel-body -->

    </div>

</div><!-- end panel-default -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a CSS @media query to hide it.. overriding the effect if the `.in`

```
@media (max-width:1199px) {
    #panel-login {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

CSS: http://codeply.com/go/Q4X15Bp31R

Or, you can use jQuery and watch the resize event like this..

```
function togglePanel (){
   var w = $(window).width();
   if (w <= 1199) {
      $('#panel-login').removeClass('in');
   } else {
      $('#panel-login').addClass('in');
   }
}

$(window).resize(function(){
     togglePanel();
});

togglePanel();
```

jQuery: http://codeply.com/go/okQQKcdO7v

Comment: I've tried that. It do hide the panel on mobile screens but it also prevent it from being show again when I click the collapse button. I want it to be hidden when the page first loads (on mobile) but still available to collapse.

Comment: Yeah, then the only way is with jQuery. See the 2nd demo

Comment: I've looked at your codeply. It works as intended there. It's also very much the same code as I've seen in examples when trying to research an answer before posting here. However, it does NOT work in my project. Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Make sure jQuery is included before Bootstrap and wrap the code in jQuery $document.ready(..)

Comment: your last comment made me think... and find what was wrong. I load jQuery and Bootstrap js last on my page (since that is saied to make the page load faster) and I had to put this jQuery between those two includes, after jQuery was loaded but before Bootstrap js was loaded. However the code from Enrico was even simpler and did the job.

Comment: Yeah, that code works except for when the browser is resized

Comment: You are right. I forgot about people using tablets and rotating the screen... I've marked this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I used:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #my-div .collapse {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually the best possible solution because it does not involve any javascript and/or jquery (sic!)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

In you panel-heading element just add

```
<span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span>
```

And in your panel-body element add "collapse":

`<div class="panel-body collapse">`

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('click', '.panel-heading span.clickable', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var d = $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body');
        if(!d.hasClass('collapse in')) {
            d.slideDown();
            d.addClass('in');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        }
        else {
            d.slideUp();
            d.removeClass('in');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        }
})
```

Once you've added the javascript snippet globally you are able to toogle every panel by just adding the HTML snippet.

To make it collapsed for mobile devices just trigger the `collapse()` function for mobile devices,like

```
if (($(window).width()) > 767) {
    $('.collapse').collapse();
}
```

OR you could check if the hamburger menu is visible

```
if (!$('.navbar-toggle').is(':visible')) {
  $('.collapse').collapse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if ($(window).width() <= 1200) {
                $("#panel-login").removeClass("in");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: That far I'd figured as well. What I can't figure is how to only invoke that on mobile screens.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry, i'm posting from my phone and i'm not completely in control of the thing. I Made an edit. That is what you need, Just double Check it for autocorrection

Comment: I have put that code in custom.js and added <script src="custom.js"></script> inside the head tag. It just wont work.

Comment: Also tried to put it in a <script> tag right before the panel in the code, that does not work either.

Comment: Surely a syntax error. I'll Check and correct it as I'm back home

Comment: I found out (thanks to Skellys comment) why my jQuery had no effect at all. When I put your code after loading jQuery but before loading Bootstrap js it worked as a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Put "in" class in html like class="collapse in"

and use

```
    if ( $( document ).width() < 768 ) {
        $( '.collapse' ).removeClass( 'in' );
    }
```